# pass special character from the command line

Tags: python, string, cmd

I have a problem with passing special characters to python from the command line. This is my script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

if __name__ =="__main__":

    if len(sys.argv) == 2 :
        str = sys.argv[1]
    else :
        str = '\r\nte st'
    print (str)
```

And these are my test cases:

```
D:\>testArgv.py "\r\nt est"
\r\nt est

D:\>testArgv.py

te st
```

I want to know how to pass arguments to python from the command line to archieve a goal like the latter case. Or how I should change my script.

Comment: Why do you have a check for `main` when there isn't a main function? And have you tried to print what you're actually getting in your sys.argv?

Comment: Try this `python testArgv.py \\r\\nt est`

Comment: @ishaan I'm sorry, i'm new to python, that `main` function is just from another code template.

Comment: @ishaan: `__main__` has nothing to do with the existence (or lack thereof) of a `main()` function. Please see [`__main__` — Top-level script environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) in the official Python docs.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for your edit.

Comment: FWIW, in a Bash-like shell you can put escape sequences into an argument by prepending a `$` to the _single_-quoted argument string: `testArgv.py $'\r\nt est'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.decode)** with the [`'unicode_escape'` text encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) from the **[`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#module-codecs)** module to transform a raw string into a typical ol' string:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from codecs import decode

if __name__ =="__main__":

    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        my_str = decode(sys.argv[1], 'unicode_escape')
        # alternatively you transform it to a bytes obj and
        # then call decode with:
        # my_str = bytes(sys.argv[1], 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
    else :
        my_str = '\r\nte st'
    print (my_str)
```

The end result is:

```
im@jim: python3 tt.py "\r\nt est"

t est
```

This applies to Python 3. *[In Python 2 `str` types are pretty ambiguous as to what they represent](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0358/)*; as such, they have a `decode` method of their own which you can use instead. As a result, you could drop the `from codecs import decode` and just change the line to:

```
my_str.decode('string_escape')
```

To get a similar result.

---

**Addendum**: *Don't use names like `str` for your variables, they mask names for the built-in types Python has.*

Comment: Why the `if __name__ =="__main__":` ? I don't see a main method.

Comment: When Python executes the module directly and not via import lets say, it assigns the `module.__name__` attribute to be equal to `__main__`. So the `if` clause is only True when you execute this module directly; you don't need a `main` method defined.

Comment: @ShenmeYiwei the addendum is something you should keep in mind, it can lead to subtle little bugs; here's a list of the [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) you must be careful *not* to override.