# Passing a string as an argument to a python script

Tags: python, arguments

I want to pass a string of ZPL codes from one python script to another python script.  The string becomes malformed when used in the second script. How can I pass a string literal as an argument to another python script without it being malformed?

**Original String**

`^XA^FO20,20^BQ,2,3^FDQA,001D4B02107A;1001000;49681207^FS^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDMAC: 001D4B02107A^FS^FO50,150^ADN,36,20^FDSN: 1001000^FS^FO50,250^ADN,36,20^FDCode: 49681207^FS^XZ`

**Malformed string**

`XAFO20,20BQ,2,3FDQA,001D4B02107A;1001000;49681207FSFO50,50ADN,36,20FDMAC:`

**Code where I call the second script**

```
def printLabel():
    label = "^XA"+"^FO20,20^BQ,2,3^FDQA,"+"001D4B02107A;1001000;49681207"+"^FS"+"^FO50,50"+"^ADN,36,20"+"^FD"+"MAC: "+"001D4B02107A"+"^FS"+"^FO50,150"+"^ADN,36,20"+"^FD"+"SN: "+"1001000"+"^FS"+"^FO50,250"+"^ADN,36,20"+"^FD" + "Code: "+"49681207"+"^FS"+"^XZ"
    command = "zt320print.py "+label
    print command
    sys.stdout.flush()
    exitCode = os.system(str(command))
```

**Code that receives the argument**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    zplString = str(sys.argv[1])
    print zplString
    printZPL(zplString)
```

Comment: Both scripts are written in Python, so why involve the shell at all? Just `import` the relevant functions and pass the data directly.

Comment: I'm writing the second script as a library intended to be called by a c# application. Just testing it with another py script. Ideally I'd have a way to handle the string as it gets passed to my (second) script. Otherwise I'd have to specify using quotes in my usage docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code needs to be written just as it is (including the rather odd way of stringing together the ZPL code, and calling a separate script via a shell intermediary, and the avoidance of `subprocess`, for that matter), you can resolve your issue with a few small adjustments:

First, wrap your code string in double-quotes.

```
label= '"^XA'+"^FO20,20^BQ,2,3^FDQA,"+"001D4B02107A;1001000;49681207"+"^FS"+"^FO50,50"+"^ADN,36,20"+"^FD"+"MAC: "+"001D4B02107A"+"^FS"+"^FO50,150"+"^ADN,36,20"+"^FD"+"SN: "+"1001000"+"^FS"+"^FO50,250"+"^ADN,36,20"+"^FD" + "Code: "+"49681207"+"^FS"+'^XZ"'
```

Second, make sure you're actually calling `python` from the shell:

```
command = "python script2.py "+label
```

Finally, if you're concerned about special characters not being read in correctly from the command line, use `unicode_escape` from `codecs.decode` to ensure correct transmission.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34974354/2799941) for more on `unicode_escape`.

```
# contents of second script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from codecs import decode
    import sys
    zplString = decode(sys.argv[1], 'unicode_escape')
    print(zplString)
```

Now the call from your first script will transmit the code correctly:

```
import sys
import os

sys.stdout.flush()
exitCode = os.system(str(command))
```

Output:

```
^XA^FO20,20^BQ,2,3^FDQA,001D4B02107A;1001000;49681207^FS^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDMAC: 001D4B02107A^FS^FO50,150^ADN,36,20^FDSN: 1001000^FS^FO50,250^ADN,36,20^FDCode: 49681207^FS^XZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Some demo code:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i, arg in enumerate(sys.argv):
        print("{}: '{}'".format(i, arg))
```

when called like

```
python test.py ^this^is^a^test
```

it gives

```
0: 'test.py'
1: 'thisisatest'
```

when called like

```
python test.py "^this^is^a^test"
```

it gives

```
0: 'test.py'
1: '^this^is^a^test'
```

Solution: enclose your parameter string in double-quotes, ie

```
label = '"' + label + '"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your string inside a double-quotes, or just import the other python script:

**a.py**

```
import sys, os

text = "a b c d"

# or '{} {} "{}"'.format("python", "b.py", text)
command = "python b.py \"" + text + "\"" 
os.system(str(command))
```

**b.py**

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":

    first_argument = str(sys.argv[1])
    print(first_argument)
```

**Output**

`a b c d`